# Type hinting decorator with bounded arguments

Tags: python, python-decorators, mypy, python-typing, python-3.11

An example of what I'd like to do is as follows:

```
@dataclass
class Arg1:
    x = field()


@dataclass
class Arg2:
    x = field()


@dataclass
class Obj:
    y = field()

    T = TypeVar("T")
    R = TypeVar("R", bound=(Arg1 | Arg2))
    C = TypeVar("C", bound=Callable[[Self, R], T]) 

    @staticmethod
    def deco(f: C) -> C:
        def wrapper(self: Self, arg: Obj.R) -> Obj.T:
            print(arg.x)
            print(self.y)   
            return f(self, arg)

        return wrapper

    @deco
    def f1(self: Self, arg: Arg1) -> str:
        return "ok"  

    @deco
    def f2(self: Self, arg: Arg2) -> int:
        return 3
```

I'm getting the following two errors from mypy:

```
test.py:22: error: A function returning TypeVar should receive at least one argument containing the same TypeVar  [type-var]
test.py:26: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Callable[[Self, Obj.R], Obj.T]", expected "C")  [return-value]
```

If I remove `T` and replace uses of it with `Any`, I can fix the first error (at the expense of weakening my type assertions) but still get the second error. This one is particularly puzzling to me because mypy appears to be giving me back the definition of `C` in complaining that I'm not returning a `C`. What should I be doing to convince it of the type equivalence here?

Regarding the first error, I expect that I could solve it by unpacking the definition of `C` in `def deco(f: C) -> C` but then I would lose the restriction that the type of the argument being passed to `f` is the same as the type of the argument to the return value of `deco`. Is there anything I can do about this?

Edit: after discussion in comments I updated the definition of deco to be `def deco(f: Callable[[Self, R], T]) -> Callable[[Self, R], T]:` and now get the following error instead:

```
test.py:21: error: Static methods cannot use Self type  [misc]
```

This seems like progress but I'm not sure what to do about this either.

Comment: Where are these type variables supposed to be bound? (Do you know what binding a type variable means?)

Comment: Type variables aren't generic, so there's no relationship between `C` and the other type variables.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first foray into Python's type hints. I expected that everything would be bound when `f` is passed to `deco`, but saying that out loud makes me realize that there's then no reason that `R` and `T` in the definition of `wrapper` should be the same `R` and `T` bound inside of `C` (if that's even the right way to think about it). So I'm not really sure how this should be written, but hopefully my intent is clear.

Comment: The right tools here would be [`typing.ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) and [`typing.Concatenate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate).

Comment: Thanks - I'd gotten the impression that those were only necessary when the argument types were unknown, but I'll take another look

Comment: `ParamSpec` is really only necessary when you don't know how many arguments the wrapped function will take. Here, you do.

Comment: Note, though, that you can't use `Self` with a static method (nor does `deco` need to be a static method; you only need it in its capacity as a function before the class is defined).

Comment: @chepner I'd just gotten there myself by unpacking `C`, however, I'm stuck again. The type of `deco` depends on `Obj`, so I can't define it before `Obj` (nor after, because `Obj` depends on `deco`)

Comment: It doesn't depend on `Obj`, really. It only depends on whatever type `f` has. (I'm going to try to shut up now, though, as I am going through the slow process of getting Python 3.11 and a version of `mypy` that actually knows about `Self` working at the same time...)

Comment: You're right - I underspecified my example. Updated to reflect that the decorator needs to access fields of `Obj`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would move the decorator outside the class. It's not really specific to your class, in that all the type information you need can be specified with other type variables.

This appears to be sufficient (at least with my mongrel setup using Python 3.9 and `mypy` 1.0.1; `Self` is provided by `typing_extensions` rather than the standard library `typing` module).

```
T = TypeVar("T")
S = TypeVar("S", bound='Obj')
R = TypeVar("R", Arg1, Arg2)  # constrained variable, not a bound variable

def deco(f: Callable[[S, R], T]) -> Callable[[S, R], T]:
    def wrapper(self: S, arg: R) -> T:
        print(arg.x)
        print(self.y)
        return f(self, arg)
    return wrapper

class Obj:
    @deco
    def f1(self: Self, arg: Arg1) -> str:
        return "ok"

    @deco
    def f2(self: Self, arg: Arg2) -> int:
        return 3
```

We make `R` a constrained variable so that we'll know if `arg` is an instance of `Arg1` or `Arg2` in the body of the function, rather than an unknown instance of one of those two types.

Comment: I apologize - this is correct for the initial version of my question, but your last comment made me realize I'd left out a critical piece (the fact that the body of the decorator very much cares about Obj). Edited to reflect that

Comment: That can be fixed by making `S` a bound variable.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you, this solves it. Just for clarification - is the difference between `TypeVar("R", bound=(Arg1 | Arg2))` and `TypeVar("R", Arg1, Arg2)` just that the latter is stricter for disallowing subtypes? Or is there something more here that I'm missing?

Comment: With the union bound, the static type of `arg` is `Arg1 | Arg2`; the value has one of those two types, but we can't say which. With the constrained variable, the static type of `R` will be `Arg1` or `Arg2`, depending on the function we decorate. Here, it kind of doesn't matter because we don't need to know the exact type to know it has an `x` attribute either way.

Comment: Is there any reason to keep `Self` annotations on `f1` and `f2`? It is redundant and not necessary even when annotating other args/return with `Self`, making no sense alone.

Comment: Probably not? I didn't think too hard about their use, but since neither function attempts to return a value with the same type as the argument, they could be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that typechecks in mypy 1.1.1, I hope it's what you need:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import TypeVar, Callable

@dataclass
class Arg1:
    x = field()


@dataclass
class Arg2:
    x = field()

T = TypeVar("T")
R = TypeVar("R", Arg1, Arg2)
ObjSelf = TypeVar('ObjSelf', bound='Obj')

def deco(f: Callable[[ObjSelf, R], T]) -> Callable[[ObjSelf, R], T]:
    def wrapper(self: ObjSelf, arg: R) -> T:
        print(arg.x)
        print(self.y)
        return f(self, arg)

    return wrapper


@dataclass
class Obj:
    y = field()

    @deco
    def f1(self, arg: Arg1) -> str:
        return "ok"  

    @deco
    def f2(self, arg: Arg2) -> int:
        return 3
```

To explain: `Self` is a bit of magic that doesn't play well with the kind of non-trivial value juggling you're doing, so I reverted to doing what we had to do in the bad old days: a type variable with an explicit bound.

`C` had to go, because not every `R` is the same, just like not every `T` is the same, so we need to have them listed explicitly in the type signature of `deco`, so mypy knows what scope the type variable has. I pulled the type vars and `deco` outside of `Obj` because the complexity of it all gave me a headache.

---

**Edit**: chepner was right, a constrained typevar for `R` is better than a bound one in this case.